# Express.js: How to serve one file for the default "/" route, then use express.static for the rest?

Tags: node.js, express

I have a basic express app and I want to serve one file (after performing some logic) for the default route of `/`.

Unfortunately I can't use

```
app.use(function (res, res, next){
    *logic here*
    res.sendFile(filepath);
}); 

express.static()
```

because that will intercept every request and send the `filepath` for every request.

Is there another way of doing this?

Comment: how about using `app.use(´/´, function(){...})` ?

Comment: To match a specific path, use an appropriate [`app.METHOD`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.METHOD), such as `app.get('/', ...)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's enough to check the URI part of url and if it's / then send file.

Check this:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) { // first must be Your middleware
  if(req.path == '/') {
    return res.sendFile('some file');
  }

  next();
}); 

app.use(express.static('public'));  // and after it You can attach static middleware
```

or:

```
app.use(express.static('public'));

app.all('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(filePath);
});
```

Comment: Option two is the standard way.

Comment: actually, didn't see reason to output static files from nodejs, I prefer to use: nginx + nodejs  connection. but anyway. I gave the solution that I think is suitable for this question.

Answer (score 0):

```
var regexp = /^\/\w+/





app.use(function (req, res, next){
  if(!regexp.test(req.path)){
    res.sendFile(filepath);
 }  

}); 

express.static()
```

this may work comment your requirement